# Scoring Items basis their Rating Distribution

Tags: scoring-algorithm

Each item has multiple ratings in [1, 5] with the distribution as [N1, N2, N3, N4, N5] and a review count as `RC`.

N1, N2, N3, N4, N5 are known and are respectively equal to a number of `1-ratings`, `2-ratings`, `3-ratings`, `4-ratings` and`5-ratings`.

How to define the ranking system basis rating distribution for say `n` items?

Few things to consider:

1. 1 and 2 rating usually means a customer didn't like the item at all.

So, a weighed average sum would look like this: `(-N1*R1 - N2*R2 + N3*R3 + N4*R4 + N5*R5) / (N1+N2+N3+N4+N5)`

2. Let's take `RC` as an amplifying factor, on the final score.

So, what should be our mathematical approach to find `R1`, `R2`, `R3`, `R4`, `R5` based on customer data, such that we are able to clearly rank products and give the right importance to each rating?

Example:

Item1: {3: 4} => N3 = 4

Item2: {4: 3} => N4 = 3

So, if we keep R3=3 and R4=4, then `Item1` and `Item2` will have equal scores.
But, if we give R4 any value greater than 4, then `Item2` will have a higher score than `Item1`. So, how to find from customer data how much greater 4 is from 3?

Also, the issue with weighed-sum-average is a popular item with say 10 `5-ratings` would be equal to a new item with say 1 `5-rating` if we take R1 to be 1 and R5 to be 5.

Comment: Five ratings of one and one rating of five would be the same for a weighted *sum*, not a weighted *average*.

Comment: @SteveKass Edited.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are asking. Are the $N_i$ known in advance? How do all five work? If you [edit] the question to show us several numerical examples with (approximately) what kind of summary answer you want from the individual scores we might be able to help. Also: I would recommend not counting 1 and 2 ratings as negative. Just look for an "average" rating between 1 and 5.

Comment: @EthanBolker Yes, Ni's are known in advance. Have added the numerical examples.

1 and 2 rating usually means a customer didn't like the item at all, and we want to penalise this rating in the score.

Comment: That's a help but still not clear. I understand the $N$'s. I don't know what you mean by "find the $R$'s". I think they tell you something about how much better a 4 is than a 3. But I can't see how you get that from the customer data. Please [edit] to give us more actual sample calculations. Maybe try to describe what your scheme would look like with only two possible ratings, 1 and 2. (I still think you should avoid negatives. If you must have them, subtract 2 from the final average.)

Comment: @EthanBolker Yes, exactly, we want to figure out how better 4 is from 3, made the edits.
(I still think you should avoid negatives... please elaborate on why and what do you mean by subtracting 2 from the final average.)

Comment: If "how much better a 4 is than a 3" is exactly what you want to figure out then ask that. Don't confuse the issue by asking for some kind of weighted average. That said, the question is interesting and I can't imagine a way to deduce that from the data. Maybe someone else can, if you ask just that question properly, with a fair amount of sample data and some rough idea of what _you think_ the $R$'s might be. Since there are no answers so far it would be more or less OK under SE rules to rewrite the question completely.